# Display ToolTip when mouse hover on Column Header of List Control in MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a scenario where I need to display a tooltip when I hover on a Column Header in List Control in MFC C++.

I need tooltip when I hover only on column 1 and column 2.

I have used the message handler OnNotify(), so when I hover on the List control header call is going into OnNotify() function. Now how to handle only for column 1 and column 2.

Can someone suggest the better way.

```
BOOL MyClass::OnNotify(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* pResult)
{
//////////////////////////
...............
// How to handle here??
..............
////////////////////////

return true;

}
```

Comment: Please change your question so that we understand what kind of window class with MyClass.

Comment: You can use HDM_GETITEMRECT directly or CHeaderCtrl::GetItemRect to determine whether the mouse cursor (GetCursorPos) is inside specific column I think.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the lParam is a NMHDR Structure

```
NMHDR nmh = (NMHDR&)lParam;
nmh.code;     // What Event caused the Notify
nmh.hwndFrom; // What Window
nmh.idFrom;   // Which Control
```

I think you could use 'idFrom' to determine which Column generated the Event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [my article in CodeGuru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/combobox/tooltips/article.php/c9283/ParentIndependent-ToolTip-Support-for-Static-or-any-Controls.htm) will help you. This was I think 2005 but is still valid.